# Can't I use graphshortestpath function at here?

Tags: matlab, graph

I want to calculate Diameter of graph, which means greatest distance between any two vertices of G.

cm is connectivity matrix of graph, and diameter of graph should be in variable a.
But MATLAB gave me some error message 'Input argument should be a sparse array.'

Can't I use graphshortestpath function to calculate diameter? Then what should I do instead?

```
cm = [0,1,1,1,0;1,0,0,1,0;0,1,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0];
bg = biograph(cm);
a = 1;

for i = 1:4
    for j = (i+1):5
        [dist,path,pred] = graphshortestpath(bg,i,j)
        if a<=dist
            a = dist
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this (I don't have MATLAB here), but how about making `cm` [sparse](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), and use that as input to `graphshortestpath`?

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/bioinfo/ref/graphshortestpath.html), "[The first argument must be an] N-by-N sparse matrix that represents a graph. Nonzero entries in matrix G represent the weights of the edges." Thus, you should not use the biograph as input.

Check our the first example in the documentation, it explains it very well!

```
cm_full = [0,1,1,1,0;1,0,0,1,0;0,1,0,0,0;1,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0];
cm = sparse(cm_full);

bg = biograph(cm);
a = 1;

for i = 1:4
    for j = (i+1):5
        [dist,path,pred] = graphshortestpath(cm,i,j)
        if a<=dist
            a = dist
            end
        end
    end
end
```